# DRBD - Why read-only on secondary resource would cause cache coherency issue

Tags: cache, drbd

According to the DRBD9 documentation (https://www.drbd.org/en/doc/users-guide-90/s-resource-roles), reading the device would cause cache coherency issue but i'm not sure about why. (**I know i can't access a resource in secondary role but i want understand the reasons**)

My hypothesis is (assuming we have DRBD-1 primary and DRBD-2 secondary, filesystem ext4 and "file_a" is a file on the drbd device):

1. DRBD-2 access file_a and places the file_a offset (or something like that) in his cache. (DRBD-2 have read-only rights, so the system thinks the file can not be modified).
2. DRBD-1 writes file_b content at the old file_a offset.
3. DRBD-2 wants to access file_a again, so the system uses the offset he stored in his cache, expecting to find file_a data while accessing file_b data.
4. We have cache coherency issue.

Thanks in advance for shed light me on about this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, what you described it is the exact scenario that can lead to cache coherency issues.

To solve that problem, you had to use a filesystem designed to re-validate any cached entries accessed by other hosts. These are called **clustered filesystem**, with GFS2 and OCFS being primary examples.

But please note that for this very same reason, clustered filesystems are generally slower than traditional ones.